# Plugin-generated pages use Not Found or Pages Archive templates?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, themes, templates, page-template

A WP Plugin we developed dynamically generates storefront pages at a subdirectory of the merchant's site, populated with product data the plugin syncs from our own servers--e.g., the storefront may be at `example.com/shop/` with individual product pages at `example.com/shop/product/123456/Item-name-here`. These URLs don't exist as freestanding pages in WP Admin; they're generated on-demand when visited.

We're mystified by some WP sites (but not all) where these pages get served up with a `TITLE` element prepended with `Page Archive -` (for the main storefront page) or `Page Not Found -` (for individual product pages), and sometimes the page content includes other elements (e.g. header lines) that seem to come from a Not Found template; however, the rest of these pages' content gets generated as expected, rather than truly coming up 404.

We have been unable to reproduce this problem in our WP testing sandbox and unable to identify why this happens on the sites where it does occur, even if we install the same Theme and other Plugin(s) we can identify from their page source.